# If Mark tells them not to dial at 9:30, why are they dialing at 9:30?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wolf-of-wall-street

In *The Wolf of Wall Street* (2013), standing, Mark Hanna shouts in the middle of the office:

> Mark Hanna: We don't start dialing at 9:30 because our clients are
> already answering the phone. Three. Two. One. Let's f*ck!
>
> *(Clock shows 9:30, Everybody in the office are suddenly busy with
> phones)*

If Mark tells them not to dial at 9:30, why are they dialing at 9:30?

Comment: I don't see anything like this in the two copies of the script I looked at online.  Where are you getting this dialog?

Comment: Without re-watching it… you don't ***start*** dialling at 9.30 you ***finish*** dialling, so you're the first one through. Otherwise you're 10 digits behind the eager diallers.

Comment: @Tetsujin ... that seems like a decent enough answer to me.

Comment: If you watch the clip, the emphasis is on the **at 9:30**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He is not telling them **not** to dial at 9:30. He is reminding them that 9:30 is way too late to **start** dialing. The place emphasis on the word **start**. It is another way to say the early bird catches the worm.  It is analogous to the saying that showing up on time is late. And, 15 minutes early is barely on time. In this case, ten key punches is too late.

Comment: If you watch the clip, the emphasis is on the **at 9:30**.

Comment: The emphasis in intonation is on at 9:30. The emphasis in meaning is on start.  Answer is the same.

Comment: More precisely, he's not telling to not dial **until** 9:30.